# Do we need install all HDP's Services Client in all node?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

We want to deploy HDP 3.1.5 in production environment
We have 3 server for masternode and 6 server for workernode
And we have plan component layout across 9 nodes above but we want to make sure where we need to place the service-client below

1. yarn clients

> First we've plan to install this to 9 nodes, does it okay or just install to 3 master nodes? Because as far as we know, yarn is needed for all nodes include resource managers and node managers

> Or is it just needed for launch yarn apps or anything else

2. mapreduce2 clients

> Same as above, we plan to install it to 9 nodes because it required for mapreduce jobs
> Do we need to install across 9 nodes?

3. hive clients

> We've plan to install it to 3 master nodes, or we just need to install it to a master node?
> Is it just only needed for submit hive apps from beeline (cli)?

4. infra solr clients

> we just plan to install it to 9 nodes and we dont know enough to know how this client works

5. kerberos clients

> Does all nodes need kerberos clients because it automatically installed across all nodes when we deploy in development environment

6. oozie clients

> same as infra solr clients point, 9 nodes (plan)

7. Pig Clients

> We've plan to install it to only 3 master node, is it related to run pig via cli or submit pig applications?

8. spark2 clients

> we've plan to install it to a master node because we just want limit it where only one server that can submit spark apps

> but in development environment, it installed in all nodes, how do uninstall the spark2 client in worker nodes?

9. sqoop clients

> same point as number 9, only to a master node

10. Tez client

> we plan to install it to 9 nodes but we dont have any info how this client works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients of any service is nothing but some libraries/binaries which will allow you to connect/access the service from the nodes where it is installed.

You can certainly restrict on which nodes you want to install the clients.

Some clients have to be installed on all nodes e.g `kerberos client`.

Clients will not use much of disk space, however the more clients you have the more time it will take for that service to start.

Whenever you start or restart service, by default ambari will check if clients are installed or not. (No way to by-pass this.)

Now all that being said, lets take a look at your scenario:-

1. **yarn clients**: Not necessary to have it on installed on master hosts but good to have it on all nodes
2. **mapreduce2 clients**: Not necessary to have it on installed on master hosts but good to have it on all nodes
3. **hive clients**: Yes, it is only needed to run beeline and run hive queries through command line. You can choose on which hosts you want to install it.
4. **infra solr clients**: Installing it on 2 or 3 would be sufficient, as the clients are needed to access the service. Unless you use infra-solr extensively.
5. **kerberos clients**: needs to be on all nodes, if not you will have kerberos issues
6. **oozie clients**: Installing it on 2 or 3 would be sufficient
7. **Pig Clients**: it is related to both
8. **spark2 clients**

   curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X DELETE http://AMBARI_SERVER_HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTERNAME/hosts/HOSTNAME/host_components/Client_name
9. **sqoop clients**: Installing it on 2 or 3 would be sufficient
10. **Tez client**: Installing it on 2 or 3 would be sufficient

Please keep in mind, that you can install it in any way you want.

I would suggest to choose 3-4 nodes and install all the clients on those hosts which are required.

Comment: 1. "...but good to have it on all nodes", Does it means all nodes is just all worker nodes or master+worker+edge? (for mr2 and yarn)

2. for infra-solr clients, how we can use its client? because as far as we know, we just can use the infra solr ui

3. Does kerberos client need to be installed in edge node too?

4. For oozie, pig, sqoop, and tez; does it means its only needed to be installed in master node? 

5. Pardon me, i don't understand this section "I would suggest to choose 3-4 nodes..."

Comment: based on this https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Is-it-recommended-to-install-all-clients-in-all-Data-nodes/m-p/225515/highlight/true#M187376,  oozie and sqoop client is needed to be installed to all worker nodes, is it true?

Comment: 1. Just the worker nodes, 2. When you have issue with solr, infra-solr client will help you to run few commands like solrctl(in newer version to connect and get the data.). 3. yes, kerberos client should be on all nodes which are part of cluster and visible from ambari ui(edge nodes included). 4 you can install them on master nodes, again it depends on how your environment is. 5. I would choose 3-4 nodes as entrypoints to the cluster and will install all the clients on those nodes, so you would have dedicated entrypoint for your cluster for operations you want run using those clients.

Comment: As per the article, to run sqoop jobs you need to have sqoop client on all the nodemanagers (yarn) and all oozie clients.

Comment: Does oozie client analogy to hive client or sqoop client?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it correctly, but oozie client will provide functions which are necessary or needed to access oozie service vi cli or help in troubleshooting. Clients are really lightweight, I would not worry installing them as they are necessary/useful to have.